# Add quantity input to product detail page

Tags: addtocart, quantity

I have an 1.5 Magento shop without quantity fields on the product detail pages. I can only add one product to the cart by pushing the addtocart button.

Now I added an input and label above my addtocart button. The input field has the name "qty". I found it in newer templates from 1.9.
As far as I can see the addtocart button has a JavaScript onclick. The new input field seems to has no effect.

What am I missing? Do I have to modify the onclick JavaScript? In newer versions the template has also no changes.

Comment: It would be better to upgrade to new version. 1.5 is way old for Magneto now. Magento has already introduced Magento 2.

Comment: Not helpful. There are to many modules that have to rewritten before we can easily upgrade. Next step is 1.9 but that will take some time. Until then we need a way to add quantity for products.